# How should my Rails before_validation callbacks handle bad data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have several before_validation callbacks that operate on the attributes being set on my model. I run into trouble when I have a situation like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation :capitalize_title
  validates :title, :presence => true

  def capitalize_title
    title.upcase
  end

end
```

I write a test to ensure that 'nil' title is not allowed, but the test gets an error because the nil.upcase is not defined. I'd like to handle this error, but I already have error handling that runs after before_validation callbacks.

I don't want to put checks around all of my before_validation callbacks to make sure the data exists, if I can avoid it.

Is there a clean or accepted way to deal with this type of situation?

Comment: The `captialize_title` method should have a check, as mu suggests. What if you were to call that method directly from some code and `title` was nil - you would get an error, so that code is no good as-is.
Also, you're putting checks, like in this case, on the methods, not on the `before_validate` callbacks - not sure what you mean by putting checks around the callbacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check if you have a title. And don't forget to save the modified title.

```
def capitalize_title
  title = title.upcase if title
end
```

If you need to patch things up with a `before_validation` hook then you're stuck with taking care of invalid data in two places. If your validation was complicated you could factor it into two pieces: one piece that has to be true before the `before_validation` can run and one piece that has to be true *after* the `before_validation` has run:

```
before_validation :mangle_data
validate :data_is_okay

#...

def mangle_data
    return if(!data_is_mangleable)
    #... mangle away
end

def date_is_okay
    if(!data_is_mangleable)
        # complain
    end
    if(!data_is_properly_mangled)
        # complain some more
    end
end

def data_is_mangleable
   return false if(thing.nil?)
   # etc.
end

def data_is_properly_mangled
   # check that stuff that the before_validation hook doesn't
   # have to care about.
end
```

Comment: My worry is that with a complex series of callbacks that operate on several bits of data I will need to litter my code with these conditionals. Perhaps it is unavoidable.

Comment: @Nathan: You might be able to factor your validation into two pieces, I've added an update that outlines the general idea.